# Remote browsing Git / Mercurial in PHP

Tags: php, git, mercurial

What is the best practice in remote browsing "distributed" SCM systems like Git and Mercurial?

As far as I know it's only possible to browse through everything if you have a clone/checkout.

I don't really want that because of the fact that it's a hosted "project management" solution that does not want to store the actual repo.

Options I have seen so far:

- Do make a clone/checkout and remove it afterwards
- Execute remote commands on the server of the company using SSH

Who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where online accessible versions of the repositories are hosted. If Git repositories are hosted on GitHub you might want to check out their [API](http://developer.github.com/) which provides browsing options. Same should apply to Mercurial when using [BitBucket](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+bitbucket+REST+APIs).

Another option for Git repositories might be using the [PHP bindings](https://github.com/libgit2/php-git) of libgit2 although I am not quite sure if you can browse a non-checked out repository.

Concerning the SSH remote commands approach, you might want to checkout the [admin defined command](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/ADCs.html) options of [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

Comment: API's are a nice entry to the data. Didn't think of that before. ADC's can also be usefull for all the other repositories. Thank you very much, seems this might be pointing me the right way.